# Converting multiple BoxGeometries into a single BufferedGeometry

Tags: three.js

Question:

How can I merge N number of THREE.BoxGeometry objects into a single THREE.BufferedGeometry?

Right now I have something like this:

```
var buffer = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

            for (var i = 0; i < meshList.length; ++i) {
                var item = meshList[i];
                var geometry = <THREE.BoxGeometry>item.geometry;
                buffer.fromGeometry(geometry);
            }

            buffer.computeBoundingSphere();

            var buffer_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                color: 0x999999,
                specular: 0x333333,
                shininess: 50,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading
            });

            var buffer_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(buffer, buffer_material);
            this.Scene.add(buffer_mesh);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't totally work. I only see 1 box (instead of many boxes). Do I need to specify 'position'? If so, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `THREE.Geometry`s, and then convert the result to a `THREE.BufferGeometry` using a pattern like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( var count = 0; count < 10; count ++ ) {

    var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );

    geo.translate( THREE.Math.randFloat( - 5, 5 ), THREE.Math.randFloat( - 5, 5 ), THREE.Math.randFloat( - 5, 5 ) );

    geometry.merge( geo );

}

geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Cool. I will try this out!

Comment: Just curious, will this affect "picking"? I will eventually like to do collision detection for each separate BoxGeometry.

Comment: That depends on your use case. Make a new post if you need more help.